# Turning multithreading code with unlimited threads into multithreading code with max number of simultaneously running threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have a script that executes a certain function by multi-threading. Now, it is of interest to have only as much threads running parallel as having CPU-cores. 
Now the current code (**1:**) using the threading.thread statement creates 1000 threads and runs them all simultaneously.
I want to turn this into something that runs only a fixed number of threads at the same time (e.g., 8) and puts the rest into a queue till a executing thread/cpu core is free for usage.

**1:**

```
import threading

nSim = 1000

def simulation(i):
    print(str(threading.current_thread().getName()) + ': '+ str(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=simulation,args=(i,)) for i in range(nSim)]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

**Q1:** Is code **2:** doing what I described? (multithreading with a max number of threads running simultaneously) Is it correct? (I think so but I'm not 100% sure)

**Q2:** Now the code initiates 1000 threads at the same time and executes them on 8 threads. Is there a way to only initiate a new thread when a executing thread/cpu core is free for usage (in order that I don't have 990 threadcalls waiting from the beginning to be executed when possible?

**Q3:** Is there a way to track which cpu-core executed which thread? Just to proof that the code is doing what it should do.

**2:**

```
import threading
import multiprocessing

print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

nSim = 1000

def simulation(i):
    print(str(threading.current_thread().getName()) + ': '+ str(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
        for i in range (nSim):
            res = executor.submit(simulation, i)
            print(res.result())
```

Answer (score 1):

A1: In order to limit number of threads which can simultaneously have access to some resource, you can use threading.Semaphore Actually 1000 threads will not give you tremendous speed boost, recomended number of threads per process is mp.cpu_count()*1 or mp.cpu_count()*2 in some articles. Also note that Threads are good for IO operations in python, but not for computing due to GIL.

A2. Why do you need so many threads if you want to run only 8 of them simultaneously? Create just 8 threads and then supply them with Tasks when the Tasks are ready, to do so you need to use queue.Queue() which is thread safe. But in your concrete example you can do just the following to run your test 250 times per thread using while inside simulation function, by the way you do not need Semaphore in the case.

A3. When we are talking about multithreading, you have one process with multiple threads.

```
import threading

import time

import multiprocessing as mp
```

def simulation(i, _s):
    # s is threading.Semaphore()
    with _s:
        print(str(threading.current_thread().getName()) + ': ' + str(i))
        time.sleep(3)

if **name** == '**main**':
    print("Cores number: {}".format(mp.cpu_count()))
    # recommended number of threading is mp.cpu_count()*1 or mp.cpu_count()*2 in some articles
    nSim = 25

`s = threading.Semaphore(4)  # max number of threads which can work simultaneously with resource is 4                
threads = [threading.Thread(target=simulation, args=(i, s, )) for i in range(nSim)]                                 

for t in threads:                                                                                                   
    t.start()                                                                                                       

# just to prove that all threads are active in the start and then their number decreases when the work is done      
for i in range(6):                                                                                                  
    print("Active threads number {}".format(threading.active_count()))                                              
    time.sleep(3)`

Comment: A2: Well the thing is that I'll use python to simulate dymola-models. The cpu-time for each model can/probably will be different so if you create only 8 threads and provide them with each 125 tasks (total = 1000 then), the active-thread-time will be different for each thread I guess which is less efficient then activating all threads and let them wait for the first thread that's free to execute the task?

Comment: A3: Ok so Semaphore is used to limit the number of simultaneously running threads but it also means that they run synchronized and that the threads wait for the last thread to finish its job before starting the next one? Isn't there there a more efficient way that allows asynchronous execution of tasks while still only using 4 as max number of simultaneously running threads?

Comment: @Matthi9000 I perforemed three tests with 100 threads, 4 threads which print i 250 times each and with multiprocessing model. 1000 threads with Semaphore 25.252382700000002, 25.2508892, 25.3252732, 25.2702972, 25.247306 Only 4 threads which do 250 attempts each: 25.3412317, 25.336504599999998, 25.3274046, 25.3280475, 25.484402600000003 Only 4 multiprocess: 25.561975399999998, 25.6724675, 25.732875. The fastest is 1000 threads, the slowest is multiprocessing, but if each of the process did heavy computation, mp will be the fastest, so it really depends on kind of test

Comment: @Matthi9000 4 threads could be slower tham 1000 threads due to Global Lock which "make slower" computations (I decreased integer from 250 to 0 in each of 4 threads) but do not affect IN OUT operations (like print), so it could be the reason why 1000 threads with Semaphore were sligtly slower than 4 threads. You can check this article for more information https://medium.com/@bfortuner/python-multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-73072ce5600b   If the answer was useful for you please mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1):

A1: No, your code submits a task, receives a `Future` in `res` and then calls `result` which **waits** for the result. Only after previous task was done a new task is given to a thread. Only one of the worker threads is really working at a time.

Take a look at `ThreadPool.map` (actually `Pool.map`) instead of `submit` to distribute tasks among the workers.

A2: Only 8 threads (the number of workers) are used here at most. If using `map` the input data of the 1000 tasks may be stored (needs memory) but no additional threads are created.

A3: Not that I know of. A thread is not bound to a core, it may switch between them fast.

Comment: A1: Thanks, didn't recognize one worker was waiting for the other to execute a task. The problem I had with the pool.map is that I don't know how to set the argument 'i' (which is straightforward with the 'submit'-function

A2: Yeah, the fact that it uses memory is not necessarily a problem but it would be more efficient that a task only uses memory when it can be executed by the OS

A3: The reason why I asked this is i'm using the python-dymola interface to run 1000's simulations from python. The fastest way to do this is when only one simulation runs on each cpu-core; performance-wise